# jenkins pipelines: shell script cannot get the updated environment variable

Tags: shell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In Jenkins, I want to get a user input and pass to a shell script for further use.
I tried to set as environment variable, but the shell script failed to get the latest value and the old value is echo.

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    environment{
        myVar='something_default'
    }

    stages {
        stage('First stage') {
            agent none
            steps{
                echo "update myVar by user input"
                script {
                    test = input message: 'Hello',
                    ok: 'Proceed?',
                    parameters: [
                        string(name: 'input', defaultValue: 'update it!', description: '')
                    ]
                    myVar = "${test['input']}"

                }
                echo "${myVar}"  // value is updated
            }
        }
        stage('stage 2') {
            agent any
            steps{
                echo "${myVar}" // try to see can myVar pass between stage and it output expected value
                sh("./someShell.sh") // the script just contain a echo e.g. echo "myVar is ${myVar}"
                                     // it echo the old value. i.e.something_default

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the variables between your stages as environment variables, e.g. like this:

```
stage("As user for input") {
    steps {
        env.DO_SOMETING = input (...)
        env.MY_VAR = ...
    }
}
stage("Do something") {
    when { environment name: 'DO_SOMETING', value: 'yes' }
    steps {
        echo "DO_SOMETING has the value ${env.DO_SOMETHING}"
        echo "MY_VAR has the value ${env.MY_VAR}"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, because this substitution works only in Groovy, not in shell code. In your shell script, you should be able to use the variable directly like echo $MY_VAR.

Answer (score 2):

The environment variables that we set in the pipeline Script will be accessible only within the script. So, even if you declare your variable as global, it will not work inside a shell script.

Only option I can think off is, pass as it as argument to the shell script

```
 sh("./someShell.sh ${myVar}")
```

EDIT:
Updated Answer based on OP's query on Shell script for parsing input

```
LINE="[fristPara:100, secondPaa:abc]"
LINE=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/\[//g')
LINE=$(echo $LINE | sed 's/\]//g')
while read -d, -r pair; do
  IFS=':' read -r key val <<<"$pair"
  echo "$key = $val"
done <<<"$LINE,
```

"

Comment: I tried and the parameters is passed, while my parameters is a map, e.g. [fristPara:100, secondPaa:abc]. may I ask How can I get it and separate into 2 variable inside the shell script?

Comment: have added shell script for reference, it would be great if you can accept the answer as this answered your question

Comment: Thanks, it work but setting as environment variable works better for my case. I have upvote this instead=]

Comment: Nothing worked for me earlier. Spent around 1 day trying to share variables between stages. This solution worked wonderfully. Thanks CGS for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the variable on a global scope so that both places refer to the same instance.

```
def myVal

pipeline { ... }
```

Comment: tried def test= "wfe"; in front of pipeline, and in the shell script echo "${test}", but it output null