# How to set a default value for a variable in case of a timeout step?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline step which waits for user input and has a timeout value of 1 minute based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48761071/jenkins-pipelines-shell-script-cannot-get-the-updated-environment-variable)

```
def deployFlag
:
:
timeout(1) {
    script{
        deployFlag = input message: 'Deploy On build ?', ok: 'Proceed ?', parameters: [choice(choices: 'true\nfalse', 
            description: 'Select true or false', name: 'Deploy'), string(defaultValue: 'false', description: '', name: 'deploy')]
    }
}
```

This is working correctly.

Is there a way to change this so that after the timeout period, it proceeds with the default value `false`?

Right now, if nothing is selected the job fails with "Cancelling nested steps due to timeout ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timeout` step throws `org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException` when it hits the given timeout. You can catch this exception and set the default value in the `catch` block. Consider the following example:

```groovy
node {
    stage("Test") {
        def deployFlag
        try {
            timeout(1) {
                deployFlag = input message: 'Deploy On build ?', ok: 'Proceed ?', parameters: [choice(choices: 'true\nfalse', description: 'Select true or false', name: 'Deploy'), string(defaultValue: 'false', description: '', name: 'deploy')]
            }
        } catch (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.steps.FlowInterruptedException e) {
            deployFlag = [Deploy: true, deploy: false]
        }

        println deployFlag
    }
}
```

Catching this exception makes the pipeline continue the build instead of failing.